# Django deployment, cannot import settings

Tags: django, deployment, config

I'm trying to deploy an application with django.

I've put my django_project directory in /home/XXX/websites/YYY.
The web server root is in /srv/http/YYY and it only contains a directory named static and an apache.wsgi file.

The content of apache.wsgi is as follow:

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('/home/XXX/websites/YYY')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'YYY.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Whenever I reload apache modules and try to load a page, I got an import error :
ImportError: No module named YYY.settings

I don't understand. Since the settings.py file is in /home/XXX/websites/YYY/YYY/settings.py, why this don't work ?

I've manage to make this work by putting the django project in the web server root directory, but that wasn't the place where I wanted to put it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This should indeed work. Can you check that your Apache user has the access rights for /home/XXX?

Comment: yeah, it was that... Thanks

Comment: By the way, which permission are to be set on the python django project files ? Read I assume, but I'm not sure about execute...